# функция работает неправильно

Tags: javascript

```js
var pol = [91, 5, 1, 3, 0, 9, 6, 8, 17];
var bit = [];

function find(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pol.length; i++) {
    if (pol[i] > 10) {
      //document.write(pol[i]+"</br>");
      bit.unshift(pol[i]);
      document.write(bit + " ");
    }

    //document.write("net");
  }
}

var res = find(pol);
//document.write(res);


/*for (var i = 0; i < pol.length; i++) {
       if (pol[i]>5) {
        document.write(pol[i]+"</br>");
       }
    
       else{
        //document.write("b");
       }
       
      }*/
```

Должно выдавать только 91 17.
а вы дает почему-то 3 значения

Comment: так вы же на каждой итерации выводите весь массив...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас `document.write(bit + " ");` выполняется внутри цикла, т.е. при каждом нахождении числа. Функция **находит** два значения, но **выводит** три:
1) Сначала находится 91, в массиве [91] на экране `91`;
2) Потом находится 17, в массиве [17, 91], на экране `91 17,91`.

Так что функция **находит** два значения, но **выводит** три.

Вот так должно быть:

```js
var pol = [91, 5, 1, 3, 0, 9, 6, 8, 17];
var bit = [];

function find(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pol.length; i++) {
    if (pol[i] > 10) {
      bit.unshift(pol[i]);
    }
  }
  return bit;
}

var res = find(pol);
document.write(res);
```